# Studio 3T tool : Avoid new console output tab on each query run

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

We are using the Studio 3T client tool to connect with Mongodb database. Whenever I run a query or press F5 key, the new output tab is opening on my console. Basically, I want the single console window that should show the result of currently executed query result and I don't like to keep all details on the separate window.

As you see on the screenshot below, two tabs for the insertOne statement and one tab is for the find statement.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unselect the `Retain previous result tabs` icon in the console toolbar. You can do it with a mouse or shortcut `Alt + Shift + P`.